# Disable script at certain window size

Tags: jquery

I have a simple script that I need to disable if the screen size is bigger than 480px. Any idea how?

```
$('.js-reason').click(function(){
    $('.js-reason-hidden').slideToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check width on click, if width is less than the desired one slideToggle();

```
$('.js-reason').click(function(){
   if($(window).width() < 480){
      $('.js-reason-hidden').slideToggle();
   }
});
```

Alternatively set up a boolean and listen to screen resize event and amend the boolean value, substitute the if statement with boolean.